# addFlags error in fragment.java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with the Logout button in my file.
The button is inside `Fragment.java`, when I click on the button I open an `AlertDialog` asking if the user wants to exit or not.

The **code** is this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

  logout.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(logout.getContext(),MainActivity.class));

  getActivity().finish();

  preferenceHelperRistoratore.putIsLoginRistoratore(false);

   Error ---------->  logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

}
```

Why give me error on  `Cannot resolve method addFlags(INT)`, how should the exact syntax be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it does not work because the syntax of intent is wrong.

**Try this :**

```
  @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               logout.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(logout.getContext(), MainActivity.class));
               Intent logout = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
               getActivity().startActivity(logout);
               AccountKit.logOut();
               getActivity().finish();

               preferenceHelperRistoratore.putIsLoginRistoratore(false);
               logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why give me error on  `Cannot resolve method addFlags(INT)`, how should
>   the exact syntax be?

because `logout` doesn't have `addFlags` method.

You probably want to start the MainActivity by adding the flags. The correct answer is setting the flags to the Intent, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

  getActivity().finish();

  preferenceHelperRistoratore.putIsLoginRistoratore(false);

  Intent main = new Intent(logout.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
  // here you're setting the flags to the intent.
  main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
  logout.getContext().startActivity();
}
```